# Is the cone of positive elements in $L^1(G)$ norm closed?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, harmonic-analysis

Let's consider $L^1(G)$, the Banach $*$- algebra of all Lebesgue integrable functions on the locally compact group $G$. Put $L^1(G)_+$ by the cone of positive elements given by $\{\sum_1^n f_i^**f_i: f_i\in L^1(G) , n\in \mathbb{N}\}$.

> Q. Is $L^1(G)_+$ norm closed?

Among Banach $*$-algebras, the cone of any of C$^*$-algebra is norm closed. The question could be considered for any Banach $*$-algebra.

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266359399_Cones_in_Banach_algebras